# Does ULID Satisfy MySQL Clustered Index Design for Primary Keys?

Tags: mysql, clustered-index, ulid

I'm considering using ULIDs (Universally Unique Lexicographically Sortable Identifiers) as primary keys in MySQL tables, and I'm wondering if ULIDs satisfy MySQL's clustered index design. I've read that clustered indexes in MySQL determine the physical ordering of rows in a table based on the indexed column(s). However, I'm unsure if ULIDs, being lexicographically sortable, are suitable for clustered indexes in MySQL.

Here are my specific questions:

Can ULIDs effectively serve as primary keys in MySQL tables with clustered indexes?

Will MySQL efficiently organize the data based on the lexicographical ordering of ULIDs?

Are there any potential performance or scalability concerns when using ULIDs as primary keys with clustered indexes in MySQL?

Comment: I don't think there's any issue. Their being sortable makes them a good choice, assuming you want to `order by id` as a surrogate for ordering by creation time, otherwise why use ULID primary keys. The only downside is using a large primary key will make all your secondary indexes larger. Perhaps you could talk about what issue you're solving with ULIDs?

Comment: Would you like to share the case where you would like to use a UUID/ULID?  We may have other tips.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, but almost no need.

- It could be `CHAR(26) CHARACTER SET ascii` (26 bytes) or whatever size the `BINARY` equivalent is.
- Yes, `PRIMARY KEYs` can have the above datatypes.
- Since a PK is implicitly added to each secondary key, the size matters some.

The UUIDs available now (both MySQL 8 and MariaDB) have a way to convert to a chronologically-ordered `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes).